# Unable to update a timestamp field of a table in PostgreSQL from hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jdbc

I have a table 'task' with a field 'updated_ts' of type Timestamp in PostgreSQL. I am trying to update this field using hibernate as follows:

```
Timestamp currentTimestamp= new Timestamp((new Date()).getTime());
task.setId(id);
task.setUpdated_ts(getCurrentTimeStamp());
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(task);
```

When I run this code for the first time, after I start my Tomcat server, I am able to update the current timestamp, say "2013-06-28 14:37:47.425". But when I run it again it updates the same timestamp, even for different rows.

Someone please help.

Answer (score 0):

seems you declared `currentTimestamp` once at instance level. put this logic into the `getter` should solve the issue.

```
public Timestamp getCurrentTimeStamp() {
    return new Timestamp((new Date()).getTime());
}
```